# AngularJs e2e Testing: How to have expect() handle non-future objects?

Tags: angularjs, functional-testing, karma-runner

## Problem

I want to use `expect()` to assert something in my e2e test, but `expect()` operates on `Future`'s only.  How can I get this to work:

```
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

## Details

The above `expect()` call works fine in unit tests, but `expect()` is a different beast in e2e tests.  In my situation I need to verify that all radio buttons are not checked.  Here's the code:

```
    //first grab all radios in my DOM
    element('.hhmInHousehold div > input[type="radio"]', 'member status').query(function(radios,doneFn){
            //cycle through each radio to check if it is checked
            angular.forEach(radios, function(radio, key)
            {
                if(radio.checked !== false) {
                    //in my perfect world this if check, then throw 
                    //statement should just be:  expect(radio.checked).toBe(false);
                    throw "expected radio checked to not be checked";
                }

            });

            doneFn();
        });
```

In the above, I am doing an inelegant if statement, then throwing an exception.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know an easy way around using a future as the input to `expect` but you can do something like this to make sure all checkboxes are not selected:

```
expect(element('input:checked').count()).toBe(0);
```

In case you haven't seen it [here is the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) for the E2E API.

Comment: Thanks, Gloopy.  That's a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the following to check if the element is hidden:

```
expect(element("#id_element").css("display")).toBe("none");
```

And to check if this element is visible:

```
expect(element("#id_element").css("display")).not().toBe("none");
```

I believe this is not the best way. But it is simple, and it worked for me.

Cheers!